# Passing variables to query with complex input types

Tags: graphql

According to graphQl docs:

> When you're passing arguments in code, it's generally better to avoid
> constructing the whole query string yourself. Instead, you can use $
> syntax to define variables in your query, and pass the variables as a
> separate map.

https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/

In this context, I'm trying to query the following schema:

```
const typeDefs = "
input OrderInputData {    
  date: String!
  time: String!
  frequency: String!
  extras: [Int!]
  mailAlarm: String
  phoneAlarm: String
  rating: Float
  comments: String
}

type Mutation {
  updateIntent(
    paymentIntentId: String, 
    setupIntentId: String, 
    pairIntentId: String,
    orderInput: OrderInputData): Boolean
}"
```

I'm having a bit of difficulty to build the query respecting graphQl's better practices, since this case is more complex than the one depicted on the documentation, due to the presence of a nested document(OrderInputData). This is what I have up to know:

```
  const dummyData = {
    date: "11/11/2020",
    frequency: "One time",
    time: "6:17 PM",
    mailAlarm: "teste",
    phoneAlarm: "teste",
    extras: [1, 3, 7],
  };

const graphqlQuery = {
      query: `
      mutation updateIntent (
        $paymentIntentId: String, 
        $pairIntentId: String, 
        $orderInput: { 
          date: String!, 
          time: String!, 
          frequency: String!, 
          extras: [Int!], 
          mailAlarm: String, 
          phoneAlarm: String
        }) {
      updateIntent (
        paymentIntentId: $paymentIntentId, 
        pairIntentId: $pairIntentId, 
        orderInput: { 
          date: $date, 
          time: $time, 
          frequency: $frequency, 
          extras: $extras, 
          mailAlarm: $mailAlarm, 
          phoneAlarm: $phoneAlarm
        })
      }`,
      variables: {
        paymentIntentId: paymentIntentId, 
        pairIntentId: setupIntentId,
        "orderInput.date": dummyData.date, 
        "orderInput.time": dummyData.time, 
        "orderInput.frequency": dummyData.frequency, 
        "orderInput.extras": dummyData.extras, 
        "orderInput.mailAlarm": dummyData.mailAlarm, 
        "orderInput.phoneAlarm": dummyData.phoneAlarm
      }
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, **prepare [and pass as variable] object for any complex input type defined in [API, BE] mutation specs.**

```
variables: {
    paymentIntentId: paymentIntentId, 
    pairIntentId: setupIntentId,
    orderInput: { date: orderInput.date,
    ...
```

... or in this case (`orderInput` defined earlier) simply

```
orderInput: orderInput
```

... or of course (if name matches) just:

```
variables: {
    paymentIntentId: paymentIntentId, 
    pairIntentId: setupIntentId,
    orderInput,
    ...
```

In query/mutation simply:

```
$orderInput: OrderInputData
```

followed by

```
orderInput: $orderInput`
```

Comment: Dzienkuje, working perfectly. The orderInput defined before is dummy data. It will come straight from the form. I will adjust that above.